# How to disable intel xeon phi coprocessor?

Tags: intel-mic

I have a server with four mic cards (mic0-mic3), and it works well.I want to disable some mic, for example mic3, now only mic0 - mic2 is available. 
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
 OFFLOAD_DEVICES="0,1,2" # run with devices 0, 1 and 2 visible
```

The environment variable OFFLOAD_DEVICES restricts the process to use only the MIC cards specified as the value of the variable.  is a comma separated list of physical device numbers in the range 0 to (number_of_devices_in_the_system-1).
Devices available for offloading are numbered logically. That is _Offload_number_of_devices() returns the number of allowed devices and device indexes specified in the target specifiers of offload pragmas are in the range 0 to (number_of_allowed_devices-1).

Example

```
 export OFFLOAD_DEVICES="1,2"
```

Allows the program to use only physical MIC cards 1 and 2 (for instance, in a system with four installed cards). Offloads to devices numbered 0 or 1 will be performed on physical devices 1 and 2. Offloads to target numbers higher than 1 will wrap-around so that all offloads remain within logical devices 0 and 1 (which map to physical cards 1 and 2). The function _Offload_get_device_number() executed on a MIC device will return 0 or 1, when the offload is running on physical devices 1 or 2.